# Execute Knockout.js data-bind : click function before href jumps to another html element

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I try to execute a function with binded with knockouts data-bind="click : yourFunction" and want it to be executet before the href inside the same tag jumps to antoher view. How can I do this? Code example:

```
<a data-role="detailbutton" data-icon="location"
data-bind="click: $parent.getLatLong"     
style="margin-right:45px;" href="#map-view" ></a>
```

Comment: What is not working, what is your problem?

Comment: After a click on the tag the href link is followed without executing the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is prevent default in your click handler and do the navigation to the new view yourself:

(Pseudocode)

```
parent.getLatLong = function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  /* do my stuff */
  window.location.href = '#map-view';
}
```

Obviously, if you have to do asynchronous stuff (as i suspect you do) you need to navigate on the response callback of that async call.